# mysqldump - git hook - what does it allow?

Tags: php, mysql, database, git, githooks

With mkb user help, I've build this pre-commit hook:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

DBHOST=dbhost.yourdomain.com
DBUSER=dbuser
DBPASS=dbpass 
DBNAME=dbname

mysqldump -h $DBHOST -u $DBUSER -p $DBPASS -d $DBNAME > sql-version-control/schema.sql 
# the -h means host.
# the -u means user. 
# the -p means pass.
# the -d means database name (same as "no data").
git add sql-version-control/schema.sql
```

As far as I can understand:

```
mysqldump -h $DBHOST -u $DBUSER -p $DBPASS -d $DBNAME > sql-version-control/schema.sql
```

Will go to my shared (OR local) host, and will do a backup of the atual schema there?

Very often, however, we change the schema locally, and then, we need to apply those changes on the remote server.

**Is there anyway I can do this follow this path ? 
Or there is a better way for doing the intended ?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: If something isn't clear, please let me know as well. I will gladly add to the question. Thanks. :)

Comment: mysqldump exports the entire database, including the data. I found this for you too: http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/git/using-git-to-track-db-schema-changes-with-git-hook/

Comment: Indeed, it was also in base of that one that I wrote this. But on the link you provide, it also uses mysqdump. And I believe we can use mysqldump without exporting the data, like when we use the flag -d (according to mkb) or according to that link, when we use another flag. Anyway, the point on my question is, either with all the data or only the schema, I need a way to synchronize local and remote databases, and I'm not sure if a hook like this will help me. It seems it only work on one direction, as a backup task, but no more then that...

Comment: Gotcha. Generally, this type of functionality is built into frameworks or build systems (like Jenkins). I know Doctrine does this, see http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/migrations for an example.

PHP itself, lacks this feature. I know that Ruby/Rails/Rake has a feature like this and it's pretty cool. Love to see something like this for PHP that's easy to use and not framework dependent.

Comment: Check this out too: http://www.liquibase.org/